# Oracle Error while executing from java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

When i make the below oracle call from java, I receive an error as "missing IN OUT parameter at 7"

```
insert into dat_cample_req(request_id, cascade_id, sample_id, cassay_id, "+
                                         "crt_sae, status_id, author, mod_sae, note, DEMCAPID) values "+
                                         "(?,?, "+
                                         "?,?,date2sae(sysdate), "+
                                         "1,?,date2sae(sysdate),'DemCap insert - Project Name:'||?||'Comments:'?,?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't put all parameter to the PreparedStatement.

Ensure you start with 1 not with 0

```
insert into foo (bar) values ?
```

And bind parameter like this:

```
statement.setString(1,"bar")
```

You have to start with 1, not with 0.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int, java.lang.String)

It would be easier, if you woul include any code at all...

Comment: The were the values passed:
preStatement.setInt(1,request_id);
preStatement.setString(2,casCade);
preStatement.setInt(3,new Integer(SampleId).intValue());
preStatement.setInt(4,cassayId);
preStatement.setString(5,Requestor);
preStatement.setString(6,CascadeId);
preStatement.setString(7,Comments);
preStatement.setString(8,DemcapId);

Comment: Please provide more of your code. I assume your SQL-Query is wrong, because of the string-concatenation with ||. But I have to see the java-context. (And I can count 8 times a ?, so I think you have to set a setString(9,"something").